# Mongoimport cmd won't pass

Tags: windows, mongodb

I'm trying to import the csv file to mongodb using mongoimport, but the windows cmd keep telling me that "error validating setting: incompatible options: --file and positional arguments". I can't find the problem and my arguments follows the documentation in MongoDB website.

I'm using mongodb 3.2.4, below is my cmd (all those below are in a single line when in cmd):

```
mongoimport --host=geosocialdb.geography.uiowa.edu 
--ssl --sslCAFile sslCA.txt 
-u username -p "<pw>" 
--authenticationDatabase admin twitter-data 
-d twitter-data 
-c yellowCabM1 
--type csv 
--headerline 
--file yellow_tripdata_2015-01.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows `mongoimport` accepts command line arguments flags using forward slash `/`.

e.g. in your case it will be

```
mongoimport /host:geosocialdb.geography.uiowa.edu ...
```

Please see complete list of flags using `mongoimport --help`

Comment: Thank you! I thought the `mongoimport --help` just tells which command it can accept, not the slash `/`, as I used double short dash `--` for ssl connection with `mongo` and it worked -_-!...